# How to separate sentence into array items, by a specific count of words

Tags: php, split

I have a sentence (sometimes long, sometimes not) which has to be exploded into a string. The catch is, that it has to be separated by length (never cutting off words).

Example:

```
$sentence = 'I slipped it into that Stevia crap that you're always putting in your tea.';
```

Should be (using 15 letters top per line):

```
$array[0] = 'I slipped it into';
$array[1] = 'that Stevia crap';
$array[2] = "that you're";
$array[3] = 'always putting';
$array[4] = 'in your tea.';
```

As you can see, some lines like **[1]** really should be cut in **that Stevia cr** but since the cut is in the middle of the last word, it is still allowed to be included in this chunk.

My current approach is to cut the $sentence by chunks of the same size, but that does cut some words. Any ideas will help. Thanks!

Comment: Is it always increased? I mean if you got 'I slipped it i' would you still want the whole 'I slipped it into' or would you want 'I slipped it'? If it is the first way , it's easier.

Comment: What if the word on the 15th character is very long?

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years I would be "I slipped it" because perhaps in that specific scenario, "I slipped it into" would be too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the wordwrap function [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.wordwrap.php)

```
 $text = "This is some text which we will use for testing";

 $newtext[] = explode(":", wordwrap( $text, 18, ":" ));

 var_dump($newtext);
```

the output would be:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(17) "This is some text" 
        [1]=> string(17) "which we will use" 
        [2]=> string(11) "for testing" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: "I slipped it" instead of "I slipped it into"

Comment: i dont know what you mean @Jack the code $text = "I slipped it into that Stevia crap that you\'re always putting in your tea.";

 $newtext[] = explode(":", wordwrap( $text, 17, ":" ));  returns exactly the array he described up in his post

Comment: How did you define 17 if OP wants the soft limit at 15?

Comment: i see what you're going for - but having "top" 15 characters a line would be the result "i slipped it" and not "i slipped it into" because later is 17 characters long which clearly is > 15. "top 15" could be accomplished by explode(":", wordwrap( $text, 15, ":" )); but since OP described in his example array "i slipped it into" and this is 17 characeters long and also > then "top" 15 characters explode(":", wordwrap( $text, 17, ":" )); returns the desired result, IMHO my answer is correct

Comment: I don't think you quite got the right idea; it should clip at 15 but if that falls on a word, it should clip directly following that word.

Comment: This works nice, but is not bullet proof according to the specifications. Still, it's an elegant solution.